What is the right negative form of infinitive?
I know the right negative form of infinitive is "not to do",but can "to not do" style be used?

@DW256 This is related but not the same. The two versions for 'not' may well have different semantics depending on context.

@Mitch No context was provided, so as it stands, the question is simply about the legitimacy of split infinitives.

There is nothing inherently incorrect about putting an adverb between to and its verb. In this particular case, I do think not to do sounds less awkward than to not do and would therefore go with that version. But the latter is more so poor style (at least to my ears) than a grammatical transgression. For other situations, with different adverbs, putting the modifier after to might work better.
I’d also like to point out that the whole idea of “split” infinitives is rather misleading. In a strict sense, to is not part of the infinitive; it very often complements it, but the base form of the verb itself is the so-called infinitive—that’s why you can have a “bare infinitive,” with simply the base form of the verb, such as get in Help me get there. You could correctly say Help me to get there, but the to is not necessary. So you’re not really “splitting” the infinitive so much as separating the complementizer from the verb form.
I believe the stigma against “splitting infinitives” arose from Latin grammar, where infinitives are indeed not split. But letting that dictate English use is silly: there is the obvious point that English is not Latin and so is not bound by its rules, but those with any knowledge of Latin would see that it is effectively impossible to “split” Latin infinitives—they are one word. So you couldn’t possibly draw from that to prescribe any guidance regarding to infinitives.
